# Time complexity for n-ary search.

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search

I am studying time complexity for binary search, ternary search and k-ary search in N elements and have come up with its respective asymptotic worse case run- time. However, I started to wonder what would happen if I divide N elements into n ranges (or aka n-ary search in n elements). Would that be a sorted linear search in an array which would result in a run-time of O(N)? This is a little confusing. Please help me out!

Comment: @krnactry: Please update your question. It has been nearly a month. The current statement makes much less sense than the earlier unedited question.

Answer (score 4):

What you say is right.

For a `k-ary` search we have:

1. Do `k-1` checks in boundaries to isolate one of the `k` ranges.
2. Jump into the range obtained from above.

Hence the time complexity is essentially `O((k-1)*log_k(N))` where `log_k(N)` means '`log(N)` to base `k`'. This has a minimum when `k=2`.

If `k = N`, the time complexity will be: `O((N-1) * log_N(N))` = `O(N-1)` = `O(N)`, which is the same algorithmically and complexity-wise as linear search.

Translated to the algorithm above, it is:

1. Do `N-1` checks in boundaries (each of the first `N-1` elements) to isolate one of the `N` ranges. This is the same as a **linear search** in the first `N-1` elements.
2. Jump into the range obtained from above. This is the same as checking the last element (in constant time).